# Using dplyr's select where variable names are quoted

Tags: r, dplyr

Often I'll want to select a subset of variables where the subset is the result of a function. In this simple case, I first get all the variable names which pertain to width characteristics

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data(iris)

width.vars <- iris %>% 
                names %>% 
                extract(grep(".Width", .))
```

Which returns:

```
>width.vars
 [1] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Width"
```

It would be useful to be able to use these returns as a way to select columns (and while I'm aware that `contains()` and its siblings exist, there are plenty of more complicated subsets I would like to perform, and this example is made trivial for the purpose of this example.

If I was to attempt to use this function as a way to select columns, the following happens:

```
iris %>% 
  select(Species,
         width.vars)

Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  width.vars
```

How can I use `dplyr::select` with a vector of variable names stored as strings?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Within `dplyr`, most commands have an alternate version that ends with a '_' that accept strings as input; in this case, `select_`.  These are typically what you have to use when you are utilizing `dplyr` programmatically.

```
iris %>% select_(.dots=c("Species",width.vars))
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you can do the selection in `dplyr` with

```
iris %>% select(Species, contains(".Width"))
```

No need to create the vector of names separately. But if you did have a list of columns as string names, you could do

```
width.vars <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")
iris %>% select(Species, one_of(width.vars))
```

See the `?select` help page for all the available options.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as I said in the question, I'm aware of `select`, and I'm interested in those cases where I wanted to do a more complicated function to a set of variable names.

Comment: So that's what `one_of` would do as shown above as well.