# Dplyr select throws a resolve to integer error, but basic select works, why?

Tags: r, select, dataframe, error-handling, dplyr

I have a large spreaded data frame:

```
df: a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 ...............
    r  w  sd w  y ........
```

I have another input which is a subset of df.

```
subset_df: a3 a4 a5
           f  e  u
```

My goal is to take the column names of `subset_df`, select these columns in `df` and continue from there (in my case to compare the values).

When I do this the simple way:

`df[,names(subset_df)]` it works, but why it refuses to work with `dplyr select`?

Here is the error when running:

```
names_sub_df <- names(subset_df)
df %>% select(names_sub_df)


Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  as.vector(names_sub_df)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
key <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13", "a14", "a15", "a16", "a17", "a18")

value <- c("G", "CTT", "C", "C", "G", "C", "T", "C", "C", "C", "G", "T", "C", "G", "T", "A", "T", "G")


test2 <- data.frame(key, value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

library(tidyr)

Comment: Perhaps, a reproducible example would help...

Comment: @Christoph updating my question, sorry.

Comment: @Christoph please tell me why the error occurs? What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a vector of variable names to arrange() in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497751/pass-a-vector-of-variable-names-to-arrange-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a minimal reproducible example using `mtcars` as an example.

You can wrap your subset dataframe in `colnames` so `select` uses the names, not the whole dataframe, for the subsetting:

```
mtcars
subset_mtcars = c("hp", "drat", "wt")
subset_mtcars = mtcars[, subset_mtcars]
subset_mtcars

library("tidyverse")    
mtcars %>% 
  select(colnames(subset_mtcars))

#                      hp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4           110 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag       110 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710           93 3.85 2.320
# ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I am sorry for not providing the example, I thought my explanation will be enough, apologizing. 
Please be so kind and tell me why the error occured?

Comment: Because you are passing a list of quoted strings and select wants unquoted names.  There are a number of answers to this question if you search.

Comment: @elin I don't think that's quite right; I think the OP was trying to pass a data frame to `select`. Admittedly that's still not the correct structure 

Comment: @Elin it worked perfectly before on my pc, when I have transferred the same code to my work pc, it failed. Will check again.

Comment: I would also suggest always using the namespace notation when you are moving things to different computers since you may or may not have dplyr loaded.  @Phil `names_sub_df <- names(subset_df)`  is a character vector.  Here's another duplicate with a `select()` example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284790/using-dplyrs-select-where-variable-names-are-quoted.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I am not sure whether you are looking for selecting columns or the values in a column. If you are searching for the latter, the following will do the job:

```
subset_df <- c("a3", "a4", "a5")
test2[test2$key %in% subset_df, ]
```

Comment: I am searching for column names in the big dataframe, I want to subset using dplyr select.